# mysql search. Require all keywords

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url FROM paragraphs WHERE 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') ORDER BY 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') DESC
```

What happens though is when I search, for example, for "john smith" I get "john" "john chambers" ...etc. How can I make both words required?

Comment: `WHERE title LIKE '%john smith%'`? You don't need FULLTEXT to do straight substring searches.

Comment: For this you can try `LIKE` instead of using Full text search.

Comment: Well I wanted to use an index...would this work with the same efficiency?

Comment: Sounds like you need the Boolean Fulltext search with the `+` operator to indicate required/and: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an additional `LIKE` clause to your where to filter out all unwanted matches:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url FROM paragraphs WHERE 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') AND title LIKE "%$query%"
  ORDER BY MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') DESC
```

Thus you have scoring and only the results matching exactly.

Comment: wouldn't this make things very slow?

Comment: Additional filters should not slow this much down as you are just throwing away some of the already found rows. Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see how the query changes its performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `+` in a Boolean search should make all words required:

```
<?php

$query = str_replace(" "," +",$query);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT url FROM paragraphs WHERE 
          MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
          ORDER BY score DESC;"

?>
```

[Dev.MySQL.com: 11.9.2. Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)